# Cloud Firestore Structuring: embedding documents together, a smart way of saving reads?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following modeling strategy to save document reads in an operation that occurs frequently in my application.

Say you have a "car_brands" collection where each "car_brand" has a number of "car_models". Instead of placing the "car_models" in a sub-collection, I am embedding each "car_model" document as part of a map within the "car_brand" document. This saves me between 10 and 50 reads every time I open my app, but I am worried about the **future scalability of the app**.

The current drawbacks that may appear are the "car_brand" document growing too big in size and the fact that any filtering needs to be done front-end side (instead of querying).

What are your thoughts?

(CURRENT SETUP)

```
car_brands (collection)
   car_brand_1 (document)
      brand_name : "Volkswagen" (string)
      ...
      brand_models (map)
         model_1
            model_name : "Golf"
            model_year : "2005"
         model_2
            model_name : "Polo"
            model_year : "2009"

  car_brand_2 (document)
  ...
```

(ALTERNATIVE SETUP)

```
car_brands (collection)
   car_brand_1 (document)
      brand_name : "Volkswagen" (string)
      ...
      brand_models (subcollection)
         model_1 (document)
            model_name : "Golf"
            model_year : "2005"
         model_2 (document)
            model_name : "Polo"
            model_year : "2009"

  car_brand_2 (document)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current drawback that may appear is the "car_brand" document to grow too big in size.

Yes, there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the [official documentation regarding usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> The maximum size for a document is 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes).

If you're afraid that you will get close to this limitation, then you consider using multiple documents for the car models. So instead of a single document, maybe two documents will do the trick. For example, store all models that are starting with `a` until `m` and in the second one all models that are starting with `n` until `z`. If that's also not enough then make a more granular classification, and split it into three, or four documents, or why not, create a document for each letter of the alphabet?

It's hard to say which is the best structure, so you have to measure or benchmark that, before using it in production.